# Is MonoDevelop remote debugging works on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, mono, monodevelop, remote-debugging

I'm using mono-2.6.7 and monodevelop-2.4, my OS is Windows 7.

I'm trying to implement a remote debugger for my own runtime (based on mono, mono is embedded in it, used lang - C#) in a way it's done by Novell for Moonlight.

Unfortunately, no success...

After clicking "Debug" in MonoDevelop:

1. IDE is put into debug state,
2. my runtime starts,
3. successfully sends DWP-Handshake to listening IDE
4. and then connection terminates and Debugging ends.

For some reasons (absolutely not clear for me) IDE doesn't send a handshake after recieving it from my runtime but simply terminates a connection.

The code i use is in another question: [Can't use Mono Soft Debugger Remote Debugging because 'debugger-agent: DWP handshake failed' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701211/cant-use-mono-soft-debugger-remote-debugging-because-debugger-agent-dwp-handsh)

Does smb know if it can be done the save way it's done for Moonlight? Or it's it's impossible? Maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prooved! It works. The problem was in unhandled exception thrown by VirtualMachineManager.ListenInternal(2) method in Mono.Debugger.Soft. More details here - [Can't use Mono Soft Debugger Remote Debugging because 'debugger-agent: DWP handshake failed' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701211/cant-use-mono-soft-debugger-remote-debugging-because-debugger-agent-dwp-handsh)